# How to split phyical input device into multiple virtual ones using PulseAudio/ALSA?

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, c++

So i have audio interfaces with 18 input channels each. Data from these devices is fed through a C++ program using a library called PortAudio. Problem is that when i start going above 13 channels per device it starts to have `paInputOverflow` issues since it can't handle the load it seems using a single `recordCallback` function. (Even tried using an empty callback function but still was getting `paInputOverflow` issues so it wasn't code related)

Firstly i thought there could be a way to chose which channels to use, allowing me to split them and let different callbacks handle different channels, but that is only supported on MacCore and ASIO it looks like, while i'm using ALSA.

Secondly my idea was to split input channels into two devices, basically having one virtual device for first 9 channels and a second one for the other 9.

I tried that using `pactl load-module module-remap-source`, although it does create a remap it doesn't detect it as a separate input "device" in PortAudio. Also tried editing `/etc/asound.conf` and trying split them that way:

Using something along the lines of this:

```
pcm_slave.firstdevice {
    pcm "hw:5,0"
    channel 18
}

pcm.firsthalf {
    type plug
    slave.pcm {
         type dsnoop
         ipc_key 12345
         slave firstdevice
         bindings [ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ]
    }
}

pcm.secondhalf {
    type plug
    slave.pcm {
         type dsnoop
         ipc_key 12345
         slave firstdevice
         bindings [ 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 ]
    }
}
```

This did not work at all unfortunately. I suspect i might be doing something wrong. But at this point i'm out of ideas. Any help would be very appreciated.

PS.: The specific distro i'm using is Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: To start with : shouldn't ipc keys of firsthalf pcm and secondhalf pcm be different ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `"hw:5,0"` try referencing the card by it's alias, like `"hw:M-Audio18"`. You can get the alias name with
`aplay -l`